# Shutdown timeout for JBoss?

Tags: java, singleton, jboss7.x

I use JBoss 7.1.1.Final. Here I have a startup singleton. At startup I initialize something, at shutdown I terminate/cleanup my stuff.
But now I found out, that the termination I can do whatever I want for 1 second! After one second the application is just away, and sometimes 1 second is not enough time for a real cleanup.

Code:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ShutdownTest {

  @PostConstruct
  public void initialize() {
    LOG.info("Initialization");
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void terminate() {
    for(;;) {
      LOG.info("loop in terminate...");
      Tools.sleepQuietly(100); // just sleeps for 100 milliseconds
    }
  }

}
```

This class does report the initalization at startup, but at termination I get 10 times the output, after this, the JBoss is dead.

How can I configure this time until JBoss kills itself even if some PreDestroy methods are still running?

Currently I start and stop JBoss from Eclipse (Poller are set to Web Port).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this on JBoss 7 at the shutdown event (based on [this answer](https://developer.jboss.org/message/917305#917648) of [Tomaz Cerar](https://developer.jboss.org/people/ctomc) from the JBoss / WildFly team).

On windows I can confirm that there is no way to do this (and I assume so for Linux).

I found it works if you halt the application before shutting the server down. That is: log on to the webconsole, navigate to Runtime (Tab on the upper right) -> Manage Deployments (menu) -> Button "Disable" for your application.

In WildFly 8 you get the "timeout" option for the shutdown. See [this post](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-2591) on how to use it.